# Using a string in JSON format in Terraform variables

Tags: json, string, amazon-web-services, terraform, config

I am creating some resources using the for_each method on Terraform version 0.14.15. The resource has an attirbute, input_parameters that takes a string in JSON format as its value. I am defining this value in a map variable utilizing separate objects. The value I am specifying as a string in JSON format, and I am getting an error upon execution that I need to declare a string. Any insight on fixing this error would be helpful. Below is how I have my resource and variable declared.

**Resource**

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "managed_rules" {
  for_each         = var.managed_rules
  name             = each.value.name
  description      = each.value.description
  input_parameters = each.value.input_parameters

  source {
    owner             = each.value.owner
    source_identifier = each.value.source_identifier
  }

  depends_on = [aws_config_configuration_recorder.config_recorder]
}
```

**Variable**

```
variable "managed_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    name              = string
    description       = string
    owner             = string
    source_identifier = string
# Is there a variable for strings in JSON format?
    input_parameters  = string
  }))
  default = {
    "1" = {
      name              = "alb-http-to-https-redirection-check"
      description       = "Checks whether HTTP to HTTPS redirection is configured on all HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancers. The rule is NON_COMPLIANT if one or more HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancer do not have HTTP to HTTPS redirection configured."
      owner             = "AWS"
      source_identifier = "ALB_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_REDIRECTION_CHECK"
      input_parameters = {
        "MaximumExecutionFrequency" : "TwentyFour_Hours",
      }
  }
```

**Error**

```
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
element "2": attribute "input_parameters": string required.
```

After updating code with jsonencode function and changing input_parameters to any, this is the error:

```
    This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
collection elements cannot be unified.
```

Comment: Try [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html): `jsonencode(each.value.input_parameters)`.

Comment: For the updated issue: `input_parameters = jsonencode(each.value.input_parameters)` in `aws_config_config_rule`.

Answer (score 8):

You have a couple things going on here:

1. The resource requires `input_parameters` to be a JSON-encoded string
2. You have the variable type as a string
3. You're passing an object type into the variable that only accepts a string type

So (2) and (3) are conflicting. At some point, you have to convert your object into a JSON string. You can either do that before passing it in as an input variable, or change your input variable to accept objects and convert the object to JSON when providing it to the resource.

I'd choose the second option because it's more intuitive to pass the object into the module instead of a string. So, try this:

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "managed_rules" {
  for_each         = var.managed_rules
  name             = each.value.name
  description      = each.value.description
  input_parameters = jsonencode(each.value.input_parameters)

  source {
    owner             = each.value.owner
    source_identifier = each.value.source_identifier
  }

  depends_on = [aws_config_configuration_recorder.config_recorder]
}


variable "managed_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    name              = string
    description       = string
    owner             = string
    source_identifier = string
# Is there a variable for strings in JSON format?
    input_parameters  = any
  }))
  default = {
    "1" = {
      name              = "alb-http-to-https-redirection-check"
      description       = "Checks whether HTTP to HTTPS redirection is configured on all HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancers. The rule is NON_COMPLIANT if one or more HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancer do not have HTTP to HTTPS redirection configured."
      owner             = "AWS"
      source_identifier = "ALB_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_REDIRECTION_CHECK"
      input_parameters = {
        "MaximumExecutionFrequency" : "TwentyFour_Hours",
      }
  }
```

Note that I've used `jsonencode` in the resource's `input_parameters` and I've changed the variable type for that field to `any` (so it will accept an object of any structure).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It definitely helps, but now I am getting a different error. I will edit and update.

Comment: Now that is one I'm not familiar with. In that case, switch the variable type back to `string`, remove the `jsonencode` from your resource, wrap your default object in `jsonencode`, and wrap your input variable in `jsonencode`.

Comment: The issue with that approach is you cannot call functions in variables.

Comment: Ah, good point @DaveMichaels. You could specify the default as a raw JSON string though, e.g. `default = "{\"1\" = {\"name\" = ...}}"`

Answer (score 4):

To add to [Jordan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386421/10907864). I Had a similar concern when trying to add a json policy to a module.

I used the `any` object type in place of the `string` object type.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

**Module main.tf**

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "main" {
  repository = var.repository_name
  policy     = var.repository_policy
}
```

**Module variables.tf**

```
variable "repository_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the repository."
}

variable "repository_policy" {
  type        = any
  description = "The policy document. This is a JSON formatted string."
}
```

**Resource Creation main.tf**

```
# ECR Repository for container images
module "ecr_repository_1" {
  source = "../../../../modules/aws/ecr-repository"

  ecr_repository_name  = var.ecr_repository_name.1
  image_tag_mutability = var.image_tag_mutability
  image_scan_on_push   = var.image_scan_on_push
  tag_environment      = local.tag_environment
  tag_terraform        = local.tag_terraform.true
}

# ECR Repository policies
module "ecr_repository_policy_1" {
  source = "../../../../modules/aws/ecr-repository-policy"

  repository_name   = var.ecr_repository_name.1
  repository_policy = var.repository_policy.1
}
```

**Resource creation variables.tf**

```
variable "ecr_repository_name" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Name of the repository."
  default = {
    "1" = "my-backend-api"
  }
}

variable "image_tag_mutability" {
  type        = string
  description = "The tag mutability setting for the repository. Must be one of: MUTABLE or IMMUTABLE. Defaults to MUTABLE."
  default     = "MUTABLE"
}

variable "image_scan_on_push" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Indicates whether images are scanned after being pushed to the repository (true) or not scanned (false)."
  default     = true
}

variable "repository_policy" {
  type        = any
  description = "The policy document. This is a JSON formatted string."
  default = {
    "1" = <<EOF
          {
              "Version": "2008-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                      "Sid": "new policy",
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": "*",
                      "Action": [
                          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                          "ecr:PutImage",
                          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                          "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                          "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                          "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                          "ecr:ListImages",
                          "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                          "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                          "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                          "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
          EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: The `<<EOF` example was the thing I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can create your **json string** as follows:

```
variable "managed_rules" {

  type = map(object({
    name              = string
    description       = string
    owner             = string
    source_identifier = string
# Is there a variable for strings in JSON format?
    input_parameters  = string
  }))
  
  default = {
    "1" = {
      name              = "alb-http-to-https-redirection-check"
      description       = "Checks whether HTTP to HTTPS redirection is configured on all HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancers. The rule is NON_COMPLIANT if one or more HTTP listeners of Application Load Balancer do not have HTTP to HTTPS redirection configured."
      owner             = "AWS"
      source_identifier = "ALB_HTTP_TO_HTTPS_REDIRECTION_CHECK"
      input_parameters = <<EOL
      {
        "MaximumExecutionFrequency" : "TwentyFour_Hours",
      }
EOL
  }
 } 
}
```

But then you have to use `jsondecode` if you want to parse this string. You can't use functions in variables, so it must be done later.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I am able to compile with Terraform but now I'm facing an error stating InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid JSON passed in the inputParameters field.

Comment: @DaveMichaels Sorry, but I'm confused what is the current state of your TF script now. Is it still exactly as in the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
input_parameters = {
    "MaximumExecutionFrequency" : "TwentyFour_Hours",
  }
```

This has to be a string instead of Object, Since you defined it as String